# Making <a> tag dynamic with Javascript

Tags: javascript, next.js

Currently my view has a div tag that contains 2 links, one for showing the page in english and one for arabic. Now I want it so that if the page is already in English this should only show Arabic `<a>` tag and if the page is in arabic, it should only show english `<a>` tag. Code Below:

layout.js:-

```
export default function Layout({ children, lang, screenName, roomName, postTitle, screenNames, postTitles }) {  

var homeUrl = '/' + lang + "/post/" + encodeURIComponent(roomName) + "/" + encodeURIComponent(screenName) + "/";

  if (postTitle) {//Means url to be set for post screen
    var englishUrl = '/' + 'EN' + "/post/" + encodeURIComponent(roomName) + "/" + encodeURIComponent(screenNames.EN) + "/" + encodeURIComponent(postTitles.EN);
    var arabicUrl = '/' + 'AR' + "/post/" + encodeURIComponent(roomName) + "/" + encodeURIComponent(screenNames.AR) + "/" + encodeURIComponent(postTitles.AR);
  } else {//Means url to be set for screens screen
    var englishUrl = '/' + 'EN' + "/post/" + encodeURIComponent(roomName) + "/" + encodeURIComponent(screenNames.EN) + "/";
    var arabicUrl = '/' + 'AR' + "/post/" + encodeURIComponent(roomName) + "/" + encodeURIComponent(screenNames.AR) + "/";
  }
  if (lang.toUpperCase() == 'EN') {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      document.documentElement.dir = 'ltr'
    }
  } else {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      document.documentElement.dir = 'rtl'
    }
  }
  return (
<div className={lang.toUpperCase() == 'EN'?styles.roundedCornersBox:styles.roundedCornersBoxAR}>
        <a className={styles.urlNoDecoration} href={englishUrl}><span className={styles.engname}>English</span></a>
        &nbsp;<span className={styles.barcolor}>|</span>            &nbsp;
        <a className={styles.urlNoDecoration} href={arabicUrl}><span className={styles.arname}>العربية</span> </a>
</div>
```

Comment: In my eyes you create only one a tag , creating general variables those contains the value for href attribute, the css classname and the link text.

Comment: @Reporter can you explain it in code format

Comment: If possible can I have a if condition inside the div tag that reads my url to check if it contains /EN or /AR

Comment: Take a look at your code: The difference between your both links are only the value for href-attribute, the value of attribute classname and the link text inside the span text. So it make no sence to write two seperate links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer by adding a react if statement in div tag. Here is the code:

```
<div>{lang.toUpperCase() == 'EN' ?<a className={styles.urlNoDecoration} href={arabicUrl}><span className={styles.engname}>العربية</span></a>
        :<a className={styles.urlNoDecoration} href={englishUrl}><span className={styles.arname}>English</span> </a>}</div>
```